# multiple toggle of classlist onclick

Tags: html, jquery, css, dom-events, onclicklistener

good day everyone this is my first post on this site, i am wondering if it's possible to have multiple classList, and will be toggle each click on the element and loop after the last classList

here's my css:

```
:root {
  --primCol: #fff;
}

.dark-theme{
  --primCol: #9A4747;
}

body {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--primCol);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#wrapper {
  transition: all .7s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background-color: var(--primCol);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #B8B8B8;
}

#wrapper:active {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#wrapper').click( () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Then, use variables from your `::root` to give styles to elements.

```js
$('#theme-switcher').click(function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
});
```

```css
:root {
  --primCol: #fff;
}

::root.dark-theme {
  --primCol: #9A4747;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="theme-switcher">Toggle Theme</button>
```